# headless chrome driver set max age of Cache-control

Tags: java, cache-control, google-chrome-headless

how can i set cache-control value by headless chrome driver?

options:

```
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--enable-application-cache");
    options.addArguments("--Cache-Control=max-age=1000"); //'Cache-Control':'max-age=0'
    options.addArguments("--lang=en-US,en");
    options.addArguments("--user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko\"");
```

ChromeDriver 2.34.522940

options.setHeadless(false);

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

options.setHeadless(true);

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: capabilities.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", true); not working